# Vue / feel confused about get props via this.$options.propData in beforeCreate

Tags: vue.js, lifecycle

I'm writing Vue2, and feel confused about life cycle of Vue.
Please help me, thx. :)

1.
If there is a prop called count.

Why can't count be accessed via this.count in beforeCreate, but it can be accessed via this.$options.propsData.count in same hook?

2.
what's the difference between this.count and this.$options.propsData.count?

3.
What's the meaning of "after props resolution" of sentence below?

> Called immediately when the instance is initialized, after props resolution, before processing other options such as data() or computed

---

I did below,

```
<!-- child component in parent component -->

<Card :count="33" :data="data"></Card>
```

```
<!-- beforeCreate hook of child component -->

beforeCreate(): void {
  console.log(this.$options);
}
```

then get something like [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayUTo.png)

Comment: Where did you get the info on 'propsData'? It's `this.$options.data()` in Vue 2. The quote explains why this.count can't be accessed. Because data() wasn't called and this.count doesn't exist at this point. Props resolution means that they are available on `this`.

Comment: @Estus

Thanks for your explanation. I added more information about this.$options.propsData.

Comment: It's this.propsData and not this.$options.propsData in your case. It's private property that you won't see in the documentation; ignore it unless you know what you're doing. The picture suggests that you use Vue 3, there's no `Proxy` in 2. Any way, stick to this https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram . `data` isn't specifically mentioned but it's presumed in "init options". If you need to rely on `data`, `computed`, etc options, don't use beforeCreate. You don't need to access $options explicitly either, it's for special cases, most times mixins or plugins